# How to get Object's toString()?

Tags: java, standards, hierarchy, puzzle

Имеется класс `BloodCell` в очень большой и длинной иерархии классов общего назначения. Важно: все классы по своему определяют toString(). Исходный код классов-предков недоступен.

```
public class BloodCell /*...*/ {
    // много кода

    public String objToString() {
        return Object.super.toString(); // ALARM
    }
}

class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        var bc = new BloodCell();
        System.out.println(bc.objToString());
    }
}
```

Есть большое желание получить тот результат, что выдаётся корневым `toString()`. Т.е. хочу увидеть адрес объекта в логическом адресном пространстве.

**Вопрос:** как это сделать?

---

Замечание: строка с комментарием "ALARM" выдуманная. Хочется какой-то аналог такого действия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(bc));
```

Важно понимать, что упомянутый в документации *internal address* - это не адрес расположения объекта в памяти, это [почти случайное число](https://toster.ru/answer?answer_id=1230726#answers_list_answer), а расположение объекта в памяти постоянно меняется, при каждой сборке мусора.

Comment: Да, Сергей, спасибо! Это я понимаю. Как раз ещё вчера искал, как узнать настоящий адрес.

Comment: Настоящий только через Unsafe, но толку от этого никакого, один вред.

Comment: Именно такую информацию и нашёл! Ещё раз большое спасибо!

Comment: Сергей, можете посоветовать что-нибудь, чтобы подступиться к созданию маленького сайта -- панели управления некоторой БД, стоящей на той же машине, что и сайт. Так же на этой машине будет запущен класс управления ботом телеграмма. Прочитаны TIJ4, и Шилдт девятое издание. Пока вообще не представляю сборщиков вроде Maven, каких то фреймворков вроде Spring, контейнеров вроде Tomcat... Не понимаю с чего начать, чтобы в голове сформировалась чёткая картинка происходящего. Очень желательно русскоязычные источники. Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: Сложный вопрос. Я не знаю хороших для новичка книг, вводящих в web-программирование на Java. Все они либо предполагают наличие у читателя  базовых знаний в JavaEE, либо ужасно написаны. Более менее последовательно в тему вводит трёхтомник Дейтелов "Технологии программирования на Java 2". Он старый и Дейтелы очень уныло пишут, но ничего лучшего посоветовать не могу. [Раз](https://goo.gl/Gb44W6), [два](https://goo.gl/PXm1p2), [три](https://goo.gl/cr4t9Y). А после них должны нормально зайти учебники типа "Изучаем Java EE 7" Гонсалвеса и "Spring 4 для профессионалов" Шефера.

Comment: Обращусь к этим источникам, спасибо! Приятно, что находите время мне ответить :3